Fortigate IP Ban Permissions needed
I'm setting up an automation to ban IP on the firewall using a script, therefore I'll use the Fortigate API.
I need a service account able to use the function ban-ip of the API with the minimum permission set for this task only.
So my question is, what are the permissions required for this account to use the ban-ip function ?
Thanks !
